# AngularUI grid: How can I get selected data after sorting?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using AngularUI grid with AngularJS 1.x.

- I performed a sort on my table.
- Selected all the rows, post sorting.
- `getSelectedRows()` returns the selected data in the original order, but not in the sorted order.

How can I get the selected data in the sorted order?

Answer (score 0):

So, we can get our hands on the sorted data, even with pagination using the below.

var sorted = grid.sortByColumn(grid.rows);

Worked like a charm for the fix I wanted.